# Diffusion and Drift currents in forward bias

Tags: electrons, electric-fields, electric-current, voltage, diffusion

Why do the current in diode in forward bias configuration called "Diffusion current", even if this current is a resultant of external voltage supply which create electric field in diode, hence should be called "drift current"?  I also acknowledge that there is concentration gradient as P side is full of holes and N side is full of electrons, but do you think diffusion should be even considered where strong electric field due to bias voltage due to battery is present there ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that there are both drift and diffusion currents in the pn-diode. However, due to current continuity in the one-dimensional diode model, the total current (electrons and holes) can be described as the sum of the minority diffusion currents in the quasi-neutral p- and n-regions at the respective depletion zone boundaries. This corresponds to the so-called Shockley model of the diode, which works pretty well at not to high voltages when recombination/generation in the depletion zone can be neglected.

Comment: Sir so can we say that drift current is much more then diffusion current when diode is biased ? Lets say that there is  a diffusion part and there is also drift part (Large due to external voltage ) of current in total current but I can't think how diffusion will make difference .

Comment: and books say  reverse of I commented.

Comment: @NandaSinha  -  If you consider the depletion region, you have both drift and diffusion currents. Even when the diode is unbiased, you can describe the zero current both of electrons and of holes as a sum of diffusion and drift current which cancel each other in equilibrium. Remember that  there is an built electric field. When you apply a forward bias, the diffusion current in the depletion zone (in forward bias direction) becomes larger than the opposing drift current.

Comment: So should I consider the voltage /electric field applied by external source(battery) as "only" to cancel the exact built in potential and now as no electric field in the diode ,the electrons and holes can easily diffuse into each other's area which will give enough rise to the current ? I am thinking that battery giving much more electric field in the diode which is not only canceling built in electric field but also "accelerating" electrons which will contribute more current ( and thats why I am thinking that it is a drift current ). Thank you .

Comment: When you apply an external  forward bias voltage, this diminishes the voltage drop of the built-in voltage, by shifting the quasi-Fermi levels of the p- and n-regions energetically by $e·V_{forward}$ . It doesn't usually eliminate the built-in voltage. The consequence is that, in the depletion region, the diffusion current  in forward direction becomes larger than the drift current in the opposing direction. The difference of both (summing net electron and net hole currents) corresponds to the forward bias diode current.

Comment: "When you apply an external forward bias voltage, this diminishes the voltage drop of the built-in voltage, by shifting the quasi-Fermi levels of the p- and n-regions energetically by e⋅Vforward " That means the "energy" is provided by battery in form of electric field acting on those majority  electrons and holes which enables them to climb that barrier (it is not eliminating the barrier ) , which means majority electrons and holes are acting due to electric field and that will produce drift current .

Comment: Ex. Lets assume there is a room in which left there are red plastic balls & on the right side white plastic balls. These balls are separated by two powerful fans one of which blowing air at the right side & another at the left side. Now if there were no fans there would have been motion and we can call that diffusion of balls. Now if I put two much more powerful fans from outside the room in the windows (left & right ) then red balls will move towards white & white will move towards red. But this is the result of air blowing by fans . here small fans (built in E ) big fan (battery provided )E

Comment: or should understand that battery voltage only decrease potential barrier but doesn't even affect majority charge carriers ? If so,the  why current increases when voltage is increased , it shouldn't as diffusion is not contolled or affect by external thins?  Dhanyawaad (Thank you )

Comment: @NandaSinha - You are right, the applied forward battery voltage only reduces the built in potential barrier for both electrons and holes. In equilibrium, i.e. zero applied voltage, the electric field of the built-in potential opposes the diffusion of electrons  from the n -side to the p-side, and of holes from the p-side to the n-side, so that the sum of drift and diffusion currents of both  electrons and of holes is exactly zero.

Comment: @NandaSinha - When you apply the forward bias, this equilibrium is disturbed, the opposing electric field decreases with the potential barrier height, so that the drift currents of both electrons and holes (both in reverse direction) become smaller than the diffusion currents in forward direction, i.e. in the direction you expect from the applied battery voltage.

Comment: WHy battery doesn't affect the charge carriers? It should because it creates electric field and in a electric field charge carrier gains energy or feels the pressure. How can you explain different currents with different voltages ?

Comment: Lets say  after .7 v  barrier loose its significance then there is some current  I1  . now I increase the voltage source in circuit which will allow more current in circuit . Now how the current will increase if current inside diode solely depends on diffusion not on electric field provided by out side ?

Comment: What am I missing  ?  :(

Comment: @NandaSinha - You can also view the quasi-Fermi for electrons  $E_{F_n}(x)$ when you apply the battery voltage (analogously for holes). Using the Einstein relation $D_n=\mu_n \frac {kT}{e}$,  the drift-diffusion equation for electrons $$J=ne\mu E+eD\frac {dn}{dx}$$ can be rewritten in terms of  the gradient of $E_{F_n}$ $$J=\mu_n n \frac {dE_{F_n}}{dx}$$ Thus the electron current flows in the direction of positive gradient. When you apply a forward bias to the pn-junction, the electron quasi-fermi level is higher on the n-side. Thus the electron (and hole) current flows in forward direction.

Comment: @NandaSinha - Regarding you last comment. The usual diode current equations hold only for applied voltages that are well below the built-in potential. Thus, in the framework of this model,  the barrier never loses its significance. If you apply much higher voltages, the current will ultimately be determined by the series resistances of the pn-junction.

Comment: @NandaSinha - The effects of the battery forward bias are: (1) reduce the opposing electric field connected to the built-in potential. (2) lift the quasi-fermi level at the n-side with respect to the quasi-Fermi level on the p-side by $e·V$

Comment: my bad I don't even know the term "quasi-fermi level ". btw Thank you for the help

Comment: @NandaSinha - The Fermi level of a system is only defined in equilibrium. When you apply a voltage, the p-side (including contact) and the n-side (including contact) can in a good approximation be considered to have each a Fermi level that is separated by $e·V$. In non-equilibrium situations, when the carrier concentration is known (by calculations), you can define a quasi-Fermi level for electrons by $$n=N_C \exp(\frac {E_{F_n}-E_C}{kT})$$ and a quasi-Fermi level for holes by $$p=N_V \exp (\frac {E_V-E_{F_p}}{kT})$$ $E_{F_p}$ and $E_{F_n}$ are approximately equal only at the contacts.